# Not able to cache the response internally when using send-request policy in APIM inbound

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-policy

I am new to implementing the policies in APIM. I am trying to access table storage from inbound policies using send-request and forming a response body. But I am not able to store the response in internal cache.

Can Anyone tell me if I can cache the response internally from send-request policy?

I tried using cache-lookup to cache the response as below. But every time I am getting response like "Cache lookup resulted in a miss!"

Please find the code below for reference.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none">
        <vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header>
        <vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header>
    </cache-lookup>
    <set-variable name="SASToken" value="@("my sas key")" />
    <set-variable name="TableURL" value="@{string sastoken = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("SASToken");return String.Format("https://storageaccount.table.core.windows.net/table()?{0}", sastoken);}" />
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="data" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>@($"{context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("TableURL")}")</set-url>
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Accept" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json;odata=nometadata</value>
        </set-header>
    </send-request>
    <return-response response-variable-name="data">
        <set-status code="200" reason="Ok" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Accept" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json;odata=nometadata</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body template="liquid">
                {
                  "result" : [
                       {{body}}  
                  ]
                }
        </set-body>
    </return-response>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
    <cache-store duration="1000" cache-response="true" />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please do not add code as an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, I have tried using cache-lookup policy to cache the response getting from table storage. But it is not caching the response, every time it is giving me "Cache lookup resulted in a miss". I have updated my post with a screenshot of the script used. Please check once and let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, I have updated the script instead of screenshot. Please have a look.

Comment: `return-response` is not stored in cache. Please change your code that request is forward to table as `backend` and modify the response in the `outbound` section.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, Thanks for your input. I tried using set-backend-service base-url, but I am not able to modify the response coming from it. I need to form a custom Json from the response.